# Android Library Project - Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, jar, export

I'm trying to create a library project to use it for a Unity3d Plugin. All is correct but when i'm trying to show a custom progressDialog for example i'm doing this, getting Resources$NotFoundException

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(com.myapp.test.R.layout.loading, null);
            layout.setMinimumWidth((int)(displayRectangle.width() * 0.9f));
            layout.setMinimumHeight((int)(displayRectangle.height() * 0.9f));

            progress.setView(layout);
```

I'm doing something wrong? My Library project ( jar file ) seems that not contains any layouts or resources... I have put in preferences of eclipse Is Library true.

Comment: Is this snippet from your library project, or from a project that uses your library?

Comment: If I am not wrong, there is no way to incapsulate resources into a jar file. The only way is to include your library progect into your game application configuring its build path in Eclipse

Comment: OK, so i think that the right way is to export my Unity Game to Eclipse and add my project as library. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot package resources into a jar file. Suggest you make a library project and refer the same in your android project.

For more information check the link below

http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html

Right click on the project, goto properties, choose android, choose Is Library (tick).

[image]

To refer a library project in yout android project

Right click on your android project, goto properties, choose android, click add, browse and add the library project. Click apply and ok.

Snap shot of adding actionbaesherlock library project. Note the green tick.

[image]

Clean and build.

http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html

Comment: I've make my project as library, the problem is that i though in Unity3d i could use it, but i see that it's not possible. So the next step is to export my Unity3d project to eclipse and do like yours.

Comment: i suggest you read the contents in the link http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html

Comment: Thanks @Raghunandan, I did it with others projects always in Eclipse, but i expected in Unity Could be the same...finally i couldn't found a solution for unity, so i will do it exporting my unity3d project to eclipse and do it like your post.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to encapsulate Android resources into a Jar file. The only way to achieve that is adding your library project to the build path of your application. If you are using Eclipse simply right click your project -> properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects and add your library here.