# Setting up android view library in project

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use the Gauge View from [github](https://github.com/CodeAndMagic/GaugeView) in a new project of mine.
The sample application that is given with the library works perfect !

But when i try to include the library into a New Project (properties > buildpath > projects > (add library project)), put the view in my layout and try to get a reference to the view in code it throws `ClassNotFoundException`

the following is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView
     android:id="@+id/gauge_view1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>
```

This is my **activity**:

```
package com.example.guagetest;

import org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private GaugeView gauge;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        gauge = (GaugeView) findViewById(R.id.gauge_view1);
        gauge.setTargetValue(10);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Can someone please tell me how to import and use this view in a new project.

I've been trying for more than 4 hours to set it up into a new project like the way it is setup in the sample project on the github page.
But i have no luck.

Someone please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16341439/android-library-project-resourcesnotfoundexception/16342126#16342126. You need to refer your library project in your android project. Check the snap shots in the link. http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html

Comment: Thank you so much ! it worked ! :) i was trying to include the jar in the build path.